# LINQ Conditionally use different fields to join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this situation:

```
Table A 
Field A  Field B
   d       1 
   d       2
   d       3
Table B 
Field A  Field B
   d       1
   d       2
   d       3
   d       4
```

I want the "4" in Table B to match to the "3" in Table A.
Here's my code currently:

```
short maxFieldB = DatabaseContext.TableA
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.FieldB)
    .Select(s => s.FieldB)
    .First();

IQueryable<FieldXType> fieldX = (from tableb in DatabaseContext.TableB
    join tablea in DatabaseContext.TableA on new 
    {
        a = tablea.FieldA,
        b = tablea.FieldB
    }
    equals new
    {
        a = tableb.FieldA,
        b = (tableb.FieldB > maxFieldB ? maxFieldB : tableb.FieldB)
    })
    .ToList();
```

When I run this, I get an exception "Argument types do not match".  The stack trace seems to point at my statement that includes the ternary operator.

```
(at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, 
Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse))
```

I thought I was doing the equivalent to a T-SQL CASE statement.  Am I going about this wrong?  If so, how do I make the "4" on "Table B" match to the "3" on "Table A"?  Does it have anything to do with my switching from Lambda syntax to query syntax in the middle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't provided enough data to answer this question.  What types are FieldA and FieldB?  Generally this should be a compile time error if FieldA and FieldB are mis matches, but I know there are a lot of new bugs in EF-Core, are you using EFCore?

Comment: Field A is a string, Field B is a short.  Using EF 6.

Comment: `join tablea` is suspicious to me. Where is tablea is coming from? Shouldn't it be `join DatabaseContext.TableA`?

Comment: You are correct @AdamSimon.  I made a mistake genericizing this code to hide my business details.  Corrected.

Comment: I see another certain issue: tablea.FieldB > maxFieldB is always false as MAX(FieldB) in tablea < MAX(FieldB) in tableb. Your condition should be reversed.

Comment: You need to create a mapping table between Field B in both tables.

Comment: Otherwise it should work. Maybe EF6's LINQ provider cannot deal with this unusual join condition. What about this:
`from b in DatabaseContext.TableB
 from a in DatabaseContext.TableA
 where
   a.FieldA == b.FieldA &&
   a.FieldB == b.FieldB > maxFieldA ? maxFieldA : b.FieldB`

Comment: Edited.  I had the tables reversed in my join.

Comment: Ok, have you tried that version I suggested (where instead of join)? Does it run or do you get the same exception?

Comment: *"Does it have anything to do with my switching from Lambda syntax to query syntax in the middle?"* Where is that switching? What you have posted is pure query syntax, which is not even valid.

Comment: @AdamSimon I tried it, but I got the same error: "Argument types do not match".  I don't know why it doesn't like that ternary.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, as far as i understood your question, You have two tables and you want to join them on multiple conditions.
The error is correct `"Argument types do not match".`
Here are few issues with the code:

```
IQueryable<FieldXType> fieldX = (from tableb in DatabaseContext.TableB
        join tablea in DatabaseContext.TableA on new Eaxmple1 //add a type name that contains defination for a and b
        {
            a = tablea.FieldA,
            b = tablea.FieldB//This is of some type say FieldB(as defined in your Model Eaxmple1)
        }
        equals new Eaxmple1 
        {
            a = tableb.FieldA,
            b = (tableb.FieldB > maxFieldB ? maxFieldB : tableb.FieldB) //and this maxFieldB is of another type 'short' as you defined above.
        } select tablea).ToList();
```

Also your query is missing `select` statement which cases the issue.

Here are some quick fixes that might be helpful:

Create a new model that contains the definition for `a` and `b` if not created already and make sure that their type should same as that of your table.
e.g.

```
public class Eaxmple1
{
public field a {get;set;}
public field b {get;set;}
}
```

I can help better if you can provide the more details of the tables.